# Who can see my Singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scope, singleton

I have an n-tier application. The front-end is an MVC site (if that makes a difference). The MVC site, the business logic and the DAL all have access to a specific shared DLL in which is defined a Singleton class.

This all works, as if I assigned a value of "foo" to the Singleton's property `Bar` in the DAL, the front-end will see "foo" when it accesses `Bar`.

The question is, what *else* can see the Singleton? If another users logs in to my MVC application and a page that page sets the `Bar` property to "Fred". What will my first user see when he accesses `Bar`.

Is a Singleton truly the only instance of that class? Or is it the only instance of that class for a given user?

What about if the first user opens another window in the browser in the same app? If he causes `Bar` to be changed in one window, is it changed in the other?

Comment: If you implemented the singleton properly, then a single instance should be visible across your entire AppDomain. But can't know that, since you didn't post any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, what else can see the Singleton? If another users
>   logs in to my MVC application and a page that page sets the Bar
>   property to "Fred". What will my first user see when he accesses Bar.

All the users see the last value. ("Fred" in your example)

> Is a Singleton truly the only instance of that class? Or is it the
>   only instance of that class for a given user?

It's the only instance of the class across a thread. If your web application runs in multiple worker threads, you will have multiple instances.

> What about if the first user opens another window in the browser in
>   the same app? If he causes Bar to be changed in one window, is it
>   changed in the other?

when you're talking about "**web application**", the term "window" is not so good. each window is created by a **request**. and each request can change your singleton object value.

Comment: OK. Given that is there a structure that is instantiated just once like a singleton but has a more limited scope? only limited to the current user?

My initial thought is to do what I'm doing with my sigleton but to save the data in the session. That or save it in the Singleton keyed with the session key.

Comment: You should use Session.